# When i type cqlsh Iam getting connection refused error

Tags: ubuntu, cassandra, connection, port, cqlsh

I have installed cassandra in ubuntu 18.04 successfully. When i run below command i 
get the following output.

●**sudo systemctl status cassandra**

> cassandra.service - LSB: distributed storage system for structured
>   data    Loaded: loaded (/etc/init.d/cassandra; generated)    Active:
>   active (exited) since Sun 2019-01-06 06:15:28 UTC; 10s ago
>        Docs: man:systemd-sysv-generator(8)   Process: 9453 ExecStop=/etc/init.d/cassandra stop (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
>   Process: 9472 ExecStart=/etc/init.d/cassandra start (code=exited,
>   status=0/SUCCESS)
>
> Jan 06 06:15:28 ip-172-31-4-16 systemd[1]: Stopped LSB: distributed
>   storage system for structured data. Jan 06 06:15:28 ip-172-31-4-16
>   systemd[1]: Starting LSB: distributed storage system for structured
>   data... Jan 06 06:15:28 ip-172-31-4-16 systemd[1]: Started LSB:
>   distributed storage system for structured data.

When i type cqlsh i get the below error.

> Connection error: ('Unable to connect to any servers', {'127.0.0.1':
>   error(111, "Tried connecting to [('127.0.0.1', 9042)]. Last error:
>   Connection refused")})

I have checked logs in **/var/log/cassandra/system.log**. and i did not find any error logs..

Here are some of the contents inside **/etc/cassandra/cassandra.yaml** file

**listen_address: localhost

storage_port: 7000

ssl_storage_port: 7001

start_native_transport: true

native_transport_port: 9042

start_rpc: false

rpc_address: localhost

rpc_port: 9160

rpc_keepalive: true**

Answer (score 1):

The Cassandra process isn't running as you can see in the `status`: `active (exited)`.

On Ubuntu 18.04 the most probable cause of this is that Ubuntu is shipped with Java 10 by default that isn't supported by existing Cassandra releases. Please install Java 8 (via `sudo apt install openjdk-8-jdk`) and make it as default - after that it should work.

Comment: i have already installed java 8. here is the output.  
   
**java version "1.8.0_191"    
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_191-b12)  
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.191-b12, mixed mode)**

Comment: I am still facing the same issue.

Comment: check that there is corresponding java process running. If it's not running - it's should be something in `system.log`. Check also `/var/log/syslog` right after you start process.

Answer (score 1):

Change the owner of `/var/lib/cassandra` to cassandra:

```sh
chown cassandra:cassandra /var/lib/cassandra
```